# Firebase webhook or callback for notification when really received on target device

Tags: firebase

have a way to receive signal to my API when sended with Firebase notification really is received from receiver? Because if receiver device in moment of sending notification is out of range, result from sending again is positive. And if is posible when device again is in range and receive notification to handle this moment. Specially I mean for Express server.

I try to find explanation or help about this, but maybe can't formulated right question. Find firebase-functions, but not sure this is the right way.